# Use Class Instead of ID (Get element by CLASS not ID)

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, element, prototype

I am using prototype tooltip which uses ID as an element. I have more then on tooltip in a page, so it wont allow me to use same ID more then once in a page. Is there any way to use CLASS as an element instead of ID? Here is what I have.

```
<div style="margin-right: 2px" id="tooltip_bio" class="">Learn More</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            new Tip('tooltip_bio', "Tooltip Content", {
                title: "Bio",
                closeButton: true,
                showOn: 'click',
                hideOn: { element: 'closeButton', event: 'click'},
                stem: 'bottomMiddle',
                hook: { target: 'topMiddle', tip: 'bottomMiddle' },
                offset: { x: 0, y: -2 },
                width: '300px'
            });
       </script>
```

Comment: Source code of this prototype needs a tweak. But without seeing the exact source code it's impossible to tell you how.

Comment: Have you tried passing the element reference directly instead of just the element's id string? A lot of libraries allow that. In general, ids are supposed to be unique - if you have more than one element with the same id in a doc, you should look into correcting that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with `prototypejs`, but if it requires an ID, just put your IDs in an Array, and iterate.

```
;["id_1", "id_2", "id_3"].each(function(id, i) {

    new Tip(id, "Tooltip Content", {
        title: "Bio",
        closeButton: true,
        showOn: 'click',
        hideOn: { element: 'closeButton', event: 'click'},
        stem: 'bottomMiddle',
        hook: { target: 'topMiddle', tip: 'bottomMiddle' },
        offset: { x: 0, y: -2 },
        width: '300px'
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the prototype documentation you can do something like this.

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
  $$('a[rel]').each(function(element) {
    new Tip(element, element.rel,{
        title: "Bio",
        closeButton: true,
        showOn: 'click',
        hideOn: { element: 'closeButton', event: 'click'},
        stem: 'bottomMiddle',
        hook: { target: 'topMiddle', tip: 'bottomMiddle' },
        offset: { x: 0, y: -2 },
        width: '300px'
    });
  });
});
```